# How to fix "Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI." in Python 3.7 http.server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

**Environment:**

Python 3.7.7
Windows 10 64bits

**Purpose of the code:**

Display an HTML report of my software activity. It uses http.server module loaded by file Report.py and the data report are extracted by index.py.
I have a script myscript.py which launches the server by calling a method StartReportTool() inside the module Report.py.
Report.py launch the server and load the index.py.

**Files & Folder tree:**

```
- myscript.py   <= call the method in module Report.py to launch web server
- /report
- /report/Report.py  <= launch the web server
- /report/index.py   <= extract the data and display them in html
```

**Source code:**

myscript.py:

```
def report():
    
    from report import Report
    Report.StartReportTool()

report()
```

/report/Report.py

```
#coding:utf-8
import http.server

import webbrowser



def StartReportTool():
    port=8888
    address=("",port)
    server=http.server.HTTPServer

    handler=http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
    handler.cgi_directories=["/"]

    httpd=server(address,handler)
    print(f"Report tool server started on port {port}")
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8888/index.py', new=2)

    httpd.serve_forever()
```

index.py:

```
#coding:utf-8
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n")
html=f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
My html code
```

"""

**Problem:**

When I run myscript.py which launches my http.server, my browser open url 'http://localhost:8888/index.py' and show error 404:

```
Error response
Error code: 404

Message: No such CGI script ('//index.py').

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

After investigation, I realized everything is fine when the server is launched by its own script Report.py:

```
#coding:utf-8
import http.server

import webbrowser



def StartReportTool():
    port=8888
    address=("",port)
    server=http.server.HTTPServer

    handler=http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
    handler.cgi_directories=["/"]

    httpd=server(address,handler)
    print(f"Report tool server started on port {port}")
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8888/index.py', new=2)

    httpd.serve_forever()
    

StartReportTool() # <======= Here is the line of code which launch the server itself inside the same module
```

You noticed here the last line of code StartReportTool() which calls the method inside the module itself. And it is working fine by this way. My index.py is loaded correctly.

The problem comes when the method StartReportTool() is called from outside the method.
I don't understand the reasons for the issue. Does anyone understand the source of the problem, please?